# Limit of incomplete beta function

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, probability-limit-theorems

Consider the incomplete beta function $I_p(rn, n) = \frac{1}{B(rn, n)}\int_{0}^{p}t^{rn-1}(1-t)^{n-1}dt$, where $r, p \in (0, 1)$ are constants and $B(rn, n) = \int_{0}^1 t^{rn-1}(1-t)^{n-1}dt$ is the beta function.

1. Does the limit of $I_p(rn, n)$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ exist? if it exists, what’s the limit?

Comment: Taking the differential equation for $I_x(r n,n)$ and taking $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ gives  [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+n-%3Einfty+%281+-+r+n+%2B+%28-2+%2B+r+n+%2B+n%29+x%29+w%27%28x%29+-+%28-1+%2B+x%29+x+w%27%27%28x%29)